# How to assign data-src for the Google Drive API to a Canvas in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-drive-api, html5-canvas

Alright, so I've been trying to find out how to do this for awhile, but to no avail, so I thought I'd just ask here! I want to be able to upload whatever you draw on this canvas to Google Drive easily, with the click of a button, but every time I try to assign the data-src for the Google Drive API, I can't. I don't know how to incorporate the Javascript into the html. I have a save button that uses canvas.toDataUrl, but I also want a Google Drive save button that uses the toDataUrl as the src. My code is below. I did this all on repl.it, so you can also find my code on https://repl.it/@AnthonyRobinso2/Pixel-Paint

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

  </head>
  <center>
    <body>
      <canvas onmouseup="stop(event)" onmousedown="go(event)" onmousemove="paint(event)" id='pixelCanvas' height='400px' width='450px' ></canvas>
      <div class = 'details'>
        <button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear</button>
        <button onclick='eraser()'>Eraser</button>
        <button onclick='smallerSize()'>-1 Pixel</button>
        <button onclick="biggerSize()">+1 Pixel</button>
        <button onclick='save()'>Save</button>
        <div>
        <p>Simple Color Changer</p>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
        </div>
        <div>
        <p>Advanced Color Changer</p>
        <input type='color' id='advancedColorPicker' value="#000000" onchange='advancedColor()'>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Preview:</p>
        <canvas id = 'preview' height='50px' width='50px'></canvas>
        <p id='colorSliderValue'>Black</p>
        <p>Simple Background Color Changer</p>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="0" class="slider" id="backgroundSlider">
        <p>Moving this will erase all you have drawn! Be warned!</p>
        <div class="g-savetodrive" id='saveToDrive'
          data-src= 'THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH' 
          data-filename="Pretty Picture"
          data-sitename="Pixel Paint">
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </div>
    </body>
  </center>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
var previewCanvas = document.getElementById('preview');
var previewCtx = previewCanvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var brushWidth = 1;
var brushHeight = 1;
var x;
var y;
var start;
var radius = 1;
var color = 'black';
var backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
previewCtx.beginPath();
previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
previewCtx.fillStyle = color;
previewCtx.fill();
function drawBackground(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
  ctx.fill();
}
drawBackground();
function go(event){
 start=1;
}
function paint(event) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
  if(start==1){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
function stop(event) {
  start=0;
}

function clearCanvas(){
  drawBackground();
}

function biggerSize(){
  radius = radius + 1
  previewCtx.clearRect(0,0,previewCanvas.width,previewCanvas.height);
  previewCtx.beginPath();
  previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  previewCtx.fillStyle = color;
  previewCtx.fill();
}

function smallerSize(){
  if(radius > 1){
    radius = radius - 1
    previewCtx.clearRect(0,0,previewCanvas.width,previewCanvas.height);
    previewCtx.beginPath();
    previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    previewCtx.fillStyle = color;
    previewCtx.fill();
  }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var backgroundSlider = document.getElementById("backgroundSlider");
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
backgroundSlider.oninput = function(){
  if(this.value == 0){
    backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 1){
    backgroundColor = 'black';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 2){
    backgroundColor = 'brown';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 3){
    backgroundColor = 'cyan';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 4){
    backgroundColor = 'blue';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 5){
    backgroundColor = 'green';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 6){
    backgroundColor = 'magenta';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 7){
    backgroundColor = 'orange';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 8){
    backgroundColor = 'pink';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 9){
    backgroundColor = 'violet';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 10){
    backgroundColor = 'red';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 11){
    backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    drawBackground();
  }
  if(this.value == 12){
    backgroundColor = 'white';
    drawBackground();
  }
}
slider.oninput = function() {
  var output = document.getElementById("colorSliderValue");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  if(this.value == 0){
    output.innerHTML = 'Black';
    color = 'black';
    output.style.color = 'black';
  }
  if(this.value == 1){
    output.innerHTML = 'Grey';
    color = 'grey';
    output.style.color = 'grey';
  }
  if(this.value == 2){
    output.innerHTML = 'Brown';
    color = 'brown';
    output.style.color = 'brown';
  }
  if(this.value == 3){
    output.innerHTML = 'Cyan';
    color = 'cyan'
    output.style.color = 'cyan';
  }
  if(this.value == 4){
    output.innerHTML = 'Blue';
    color = 'blue'
    output.style.color = 'blue';
  }
  if(this.value == 5){
    output.innerHTML = 'Green';
    color = 'green';
    output.style.color = 'green';
  }
  if(this.value == 6){
    output.innerHTML = 'Magenta';
    color = 'magenta';
    output.style.color = 'magenta';
  }
  if(this.value == 7){
    output.innerHTML = 'Orange';
    color = 'orange';
    output.style.color = 'orange';
  }
  if(this.value == 8){
    output.innerHTML = 'Pink';
    color = 'pink';
    output.style.color = 'pink';
  }
  if(this.value == 9){
    output.innerHTML = 'Violet';
    color = 'violet';
    output.style.color = 'violet';
  }
  if(this.value == 10){
    output.innerHTML = 'Red';
    color = 'red';
    output.style.color = 'red';
  }
  if(this.value == 11){
    output.innerHTML = 'Yellow';
    color = 'yellow';
    output.style.color = 'yellow';
  }
  if(this.value == 12){
    output.innerHTML = 'White';
    color = 'white';
    output.style.color = 'white';
  }
  previewCtx.clearRect(0,0,previewCanvas.width,previewCanvas.height);
  previewCtx.beginPath();
  previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  previewCtx.fillStyle = color;
  previewCtx.fill();
}

function eraser(){
  color = backgroundColor;
  previewCtx.clearRect(0,0,previewCanvas.width,previewCanvas.height);
  previewCtx.beginPath();
  previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  previewCtx.fillStyle = 'lightgrey';
  previewCtx.stroke();
  previewCtx.fill();
}

function advancedColor(){
  color = document.getElementById('advancedColorPicker').value;
  previewCtx.clearRect(0,0,previewCanvas.width,previewCanvas.height);
  previewCtx.beginPath();
  previewCtx.arc(25,25,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  previewCtx.fillStyle = color;
  previewCtx.fill();
}

function save(){
  var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
  window.location.href=image;
}

document.getElementById('saveToDrive');
console.log(saveToDrive.data);
```

CSS:

```
#pixelCanvas{
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  cursor: 
}

#colorSliderValue{
  position: relative;
  text-Shadow: -0.5px -0.5px 0 #000, 0.5px -0.5px 0 #000, -0.5px 0.5px 0 #000, 0.5px 0.5px 0 #000;
}

#preview{
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:lightgrey;
}

.details{
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive) documentation on the `data-src` attribute/parameter:

> `data-src` is a required parameter containing the URL of the file to be saved.
>
> - URLs can be absolute or relative.
> - The `data-src` URL can be served from the same domain, subdomain, and protocol as the domain where the button is hosted. You must use matching protocols between the page and the data source.
> - **Data URIs and `file://` URLs are not supported.**
> - Due to the browser's same origin policy, this URL must be served from the same domain as the page upon which it is placed, or be accessible using Cross Origin Research Sharing (CORS). If the button and resource are on different domains, refer to [Handle buttons and resources on different domains](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive#domain).(#domain).
> - To serve the file when the same page is served by both http and https, specify the resource without a protocol such as `data-src="//example.com/files/file.pdf"`, which uses the appropriate protocol based on how the hosting page was accessed.

It is explicitly stated that Data URIs are not supported for this method.

As an alternative, I suggest you use the Drive API [`Files: Create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method. Upon clicking the "save" button, you can use the Canvas' [toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method to convert it into a `image/png` blob (or if you prefer, you can specify another output mimetype for it such as `image/jpeg`) and then make the `Create` request. For that, I suggest you check out the following links as I believe they can be useful to you:

- [Using gAPI on Javascript](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gapi-the-google-apis-client-library-for-browser-javascript-5896b12dbbd5)
- [Uploading files to Google Drive using Javascript](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/bd53b366aedef70e35a35f449c51eced)